# How to perform Repeated Measures MANOVA, with unbalanced design

Tags: repeated-measures, unbalanced-classes, manova

I am analysing data from a vaccination study and I think that the best way to model my data is with a repeated measures multivariate ANOVA. Because I have different #'s of subjects in each study cohort, my design is also unbalanced.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I am working in R.

Some details about my setup:

I have 3 dependent variables (3 Antibodies for example) that are measured before and after vaccination in 3 cohorts. I would like to test at least 2 hypotheses:

1. Per cohort, is there a significant difference between Day 0 and Day 30 (did the vaccine work)?
2. Are there differences between cohorts in terms of the difference between Day 0 and Day 30. (Did the vaccine work in Cohort A better than Cohort C?)

The experiment design has the following structure:

- I have a time factor (Day 0 and Day 30)
- A cohort factor (Cohort A, B, C) - unbalanced
- and 3 levels of my dependent variable which might have some degree of correlation (Antibody X, Y, and Z).

Edit: I realised in the link I provided below that the data is not available. I have coded it below, and the tutorial can be followed with these data from the beginning. For the unbalanced example, rows are removed at the end of the tutorial.
bloodprs and temprtr are the dependent variables but only temprtr is used in the example. My question is now: How can I perform a similar analysis as in the tutorial but now using both of these dependent variables?

```
group <- c( rep(1, 6),  rep(2, 6), rep(3, 6) )
subject <- sort( rep(1:9, 2) )
treat <- rep(1:2, 9)
bloodprs <- c( 3,4,5,9,11,14,2,1,8,9,10,9,7,4,8,10,9,12 )
temprtr <- c( 8,14,11,18,16,22,6,8,12,14,9,10,10,10,14,18,15,22 )
df <- cbind(group, subject, treat, bloodprs, temprtr)
```

Comment: You need to tell us more details, so we can understand the design. Maybe share (a link to) the data?

Comment: Good point!! I was able to find a document online that partially solves my problem: https://psych.wisc.edu/moore/Rpdf/610-R11_MixedDesign.pdf. Here the author performs a Repeated measures ANOVA with 3 groups (unbalanced). But there is only one dependent variable. So, my more specific question is: how can I do this analysis with multiple dependent variables? It might be useful to use the data from this tutorial as an example, since there are indeed 2 dep variables but only one is used in the tutorial to illustrate the example.